# How can I reset UserDefaults for XCTestCase?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, swift3, xctest

I'm trying to be good and writing unit tests for my classes, but I have some classes that deal with preferences and checking for first run.  The test functions I've written work fine the first time they're run, but subsequent tests fail because the preferences already have a value.  Setting the object to `nil` results in `Optional<Any>` value which does not equal `nil` when fetched with `UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:)`.

I have also tried `UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey:)` and `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` and `UserDefaults.resetStandardUserDefaults()`.  Nothing seems to work and `Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier` value is `nil` which means I can't use `UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName:)` either!

I have discovered the preferences are being saved in: `/Users/<name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<UUID>/data/Library/Preferences/xctest.plist` and I've tried using the string `"xctest"` in `removePersistentDomain` and that too does not work.

I *can* set the value to some other value and check against that, but I really hate to junk up my code to test for a situation only ever present in the XCTest (I already have a function that is dedicated to doing this reset because the `UserDefaults` within the XCTest cases are different than the `UserDefaults` within the code!), so how on earth can I reset the standard `UserDefaults` in an XCTestCase?

Comment: Bumping this so it gets seen again

Answer (score 0):

Without a concrete example, it's difficult to solve your problem, but here's what has worked for me.

When I need UserDefaults within a class, I define the class initializer to take a UserDefaults instance, like this:

```swift
class Foo {

    private let userDefaults: UserDefaults

    init(userDefaults: UserDefaults = .standard) {
        self.userDefaults = userDefaults
    }
}
```

Then I can inject a throw-away UserDefaults instance for testing like this:

```swift
class FooTests: XCTestCase {

    let userDefaultsSuiteName = "FooTests"
    var userDefaults: UserDefaults!
    var foo: Foo!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: userDefaultsSuiteName)
        foo = Foo(userDefaults: userDefaults)
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        userDefaults.removePersistentDomain(forName: userDefaultsSuiteName)
    }
}
```